# chamar uma função dentro de outra função em js

Tags: javascript

Olá, pra não ter que repetir o mesmo código 2x e mudar só o finalzinho eu queria fazer 3 funções diferentes, a vetores() e as duas que irão chamar a vetores() e depois executar o código delas, mas não estou conseguindo, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
var i;
function vetores() {
    var n = new Array(10);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var input = "input";
        var inputNumero = "" + i.toString();
        var inputId = input.concat(inputNumero);
        n[i] = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    }
}
function calcularMaior() {
    function vetores();
    var max = Math.max(...n);
    alert("Maior valor: " + max);
}
function calcularMenor() {
    function vetores();
    var min = Math.min(...n);
    alert("Menor valor: " + min);
}
```

Comment: Remova a palavra-chave `function` quando for usar a função, ela só é usada na definição.

Comment: ainda não quer ir, no log do chrome da isso:
scripts.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at calcularMaior (scripts.js:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):34)
calcularMaior @ scripts.js:13
onclick @ (index):34
caso queria uma print: https://prnt.sc/jm6pkp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o código, está um pouco confuso e não foi passado o HTML. Tentei ajustar o código para remover os erros do jeito que entendi, veja se ajuda:

```js
function vetores() {    
    var i;
    var n = new Array(10);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var input = "input";
        var inputNumero = "" + i.toString();
        var inputId = input.concat(inputNumero);
        n[i] = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    }
    return n;
}
function calcularMaior() {
    var n = vetores();
    var max = Math.max(...n);
    alert("Maior valor: " + max);
}
function calcularMenor() {
    var n = vetores();
    var min = Math.min(...n);
    alert("Menor valor: " + min);
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, eu ainda não sei usar return, meu professor não passou isso ainda e to tentando aprender por fora, com sua resposta já me deu uma boa ideia.